# Issue while running dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am getting below error while running dataflow job. I am trying to update my existing beam version to 2.11.0 but I am getting below error at run time.

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class
>   org.apache.beam.model.pipeline.v1.RunnerApi$StandardPTransforms$Primitives
>   does not implement the requested interface
>   com.google.protobuf.ProtocolMessageEnum   at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.BeamUrns.getUrn(BeamUrns.java:27)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PTransformTranslation.(PTransformTranslation.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.UnconsumedReads$1.visitValue(UnconsumedReads.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:666)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:649)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:649)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:649)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$600(TransformHierarchy.java:311)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:245)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:458)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.UnconsumedReads.ensureAllReadsConsumed(UnconsumedReads.java:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.replaceTransforms(DataflowRunner.java:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:660)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:173)
>     at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:313)  at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:299)

Comment: Do you have the same exception when running on direct runner?

Comment: Hi Rui, yes its running fine with direct runner. I am getting this error only while running with DataflowRunner

Comment: Hi Rui, just adding one more point here - my code is working fine till Beam version 2.5.0. It breaks as soon as i change it to 2.6.0 or next versions with same error.

Comment: Tagging @RuiWang for notification

Comment: Clarification - when you say "update your pipeline" you mean an in-place update of the running pipeline, yes?

Comment: @KennKnowles, I have a beam job which is streaming data from Google PubSub and is running on version 2.2.0.
Since 2.2.0 is not going to be supported anymore, I tried to update the beam to 2.11.0 but I am getting above error. 
Updating the pipeline till 2.5.0 works fine, 2.6.0 and next versions break the code. 
I hope this clarification helps. 
Please let me know if any other questions

Comment: @Ravi You are getting this error on the computer you are using to launch/update, not the worker, right?

Comment: @KennKnowles - Yes, correct. I get it when I try to launch from my system and run the pipeline on Google Cloud.

Comment: Can you please show what is on your classpath?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough rep to leave a comment, but I ran into this issue and later figured out that my problem was that I had different beam versions in my pom.xml. Some had 2.19 and some had 2.20.

I would do a quick search of your versions in the pom or gradle file to make sure they are all the same.

Answer (score 2):

This may be caused by incompatible dependencies. I successfully upgraded beam from 2.2.0 to 2.20.0 by upgrading the dependencies at the same time.

```
beam.version: 2.20.0
guava.version: 29.0-jre
bigquery.version: v2-rev20191211-1.30.9
google-api-client.version: 1.30.9
google-http-client.version: 1.34.0
pubsub.version: v1-rev20200312-1.30.9
```

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that the version of `com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java` that Beam was built with does not match the version at runtime. Does your pipeline code also depend on protocol buffers?

UPDATE: I have filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6839 to track this. It is not expected.

Comment: No my pipeline code doesn't have any protocol buffers.

Comment: See update. I also notice that 2.7 and beyond have protobuf updated compared to 2.5 and below. Did you recompile or are you running the same binaries with new dependencies?

Comment: Can you reply on the bug with some steps to reproduce if you can share them?